# Annotating a ref callback

Tags: flowtype

Is annotating the callback of a ref as a HTMLElement the best approach? I assume 99% of the time this is going to be the type, no?

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-string-refs.md

```
<input type="text" ref={(ref: HTMLElement) => this.myTextInput = ref} />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, Flow does not particularly understand the `ref` property, and will let you set the `ref` property to anything. I couldn't find a GitHub issue tracking this, [so I opened one](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2202).

So as far as Flow's concerned, all it cares about is that the expression that you pass to the `ref` parameter typechecks. So it will allow you to write

```
<Foo ref={123} />
```

but not

```
<Foo ref={"boom" * 10} />
```

I'm not an expert on React refs, but yeah, it does sound like an `input` element will be passed an `HTMLInputElement`, which is a subtype of `HTMLElement`. So using `HTMLElement` or `HTMLInputElement` should express what you intend.

Comment: Thanks for opening an issue and the response.

Comment: HTMLElement seems ok, but will it work with svg too ? I can't find anything about this, and the APIs seems to differ a little (if I use an HTMLElement, then Flow is worried that I call .getBBox, which seems specific to svg)